# laravel call to undefined method addEagerConstraints()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models

Post.php

> id
>
> post
>
> show_id
>
> type = 'movie' or 'tv'

Show.php

> id // this only auto increment counter ids
>   show_id
>
> show_type = 'movie' or 'tv'

the thing is show can be either tv or movie and may two with the same show_id for exmaple one tv could have a show_id of 10 and also one movie can have it but the types are diffrent

i have in post model

```
public function show(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Show', 'show_id');
    }
```

in show model

```
public function post(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'id');
}
```

this relationship get the first show with matching show id it sees, wheather its a movie or tv, i want to restrict it to match type column on both sides

Comment: You should formulate an answer to your own question. I am glad you found the answer. I also learned a bit along the way.

Answer (score 2):

post.php:

```
public function show() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Show', 'show_id', 'show_id')
                ->where('type', $this->type);
}
```

show.php

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'show_id', 'show_id')
                ->where('type', $this->show_type);
}
```

### UPDATE (the code above *does not* work!)

> Trying to use where clauses (like in the example below) won't work when eager loading the relationship because at the time the relationship is processed `$this->f2` is `null`.

Read more here: [Compoships](https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships)

Comment: no, a post may dont have a show linked to, but i think this fine enough, i believe to will return empty collection if post doesn't have a show associated with righ?

Comment: it should be *null*; be sure to check that :)

Comment: man, i just try it it gives an error Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Comment: i tried eager loading in the inverse relationship but its giving null , which means query is wrongly built

Comment: Hmm... well, belongsTo is the incorrect method anyway. I updated answer, but it's unlikely to fix. Please update question with Show and Post models (at least with relationship methods and table layout).

Comment: idont think belongsTo is wrong : there might be show with not a single post associate with, and also posts with no show associated with,   and one show can be linked to many posts but one post can be linked to only one show

Comment: belongsTo is an inverse 1:1 relation, but this is technically a 1:N

Comment: check docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: belongsTo() is used for both  1:1 , 1:N inverse

Comment: Ah, okay, nvm then --- just a thought. I will look into this more in a bit.

Comment: @MohamedKira would you mind posting the complete error?

Comment: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Comment: Line number, file name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180912/discussion-between-mohamed-kira-and-rafael).

Answer (score 1):

I just came accross a package https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships
what it does it allows creating relationships based on more than one FK, which laravel doesnt support by default

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a polymorphic relation.  Instead of having a model that may be one of two "types" there should probably be two separate models on the same relation.  For example:

```
class Post 
{
    public function Show() 
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
 }

class TvShow
{
    public function Post() 
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Post', 'show');
    }
 }
class Movie
{
    public function Post() 
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Post', 'show');
    }
 }
```

Then your posts table would have a `show_id` and `show_type` field that would relate to either a tv show or movie.  Check out the docs for more info, I'm not sure of the rest of your project so I'm not 100% this will fit but anytime you start putting "_type" fields in your table you should question whether or not you should be using a polymorphic relation.  This will also likely keep your models cleaner and free of a bunch of if statements as you realize there are other differences between movies and shows and how you handle them.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Show is a single model with a type attribute; it's not a polymorphic relation

Comment: I think your trying to cram a polymorphic relation where there should be two separate models into one. I'll expand my answer a bit...

Comment: He has a Show model that has different types for movie or tv AND his Post model also has a type attribute for movie or tv

Comment: Yes but his post model also has a "show_id" field so together with the show_type it's just referencing a "show" which could be either TV or Movie and should probably be their own separate models.

Comment: yes this would be a neat solution but iam stuck with the current model, iam not in a position where i can change it.  anywho for a quick fix , if one post is associated with a movie the collection will have $collection['tv'] = null , $collec tion['movie'] = data         i dont want that, "to be more specific i need the post model to return the data under $collection['show'], its just a matter of changing the names now, i can have two methods in Post model for tv and movies but the data matches the conditions should be be accessed as $collection['show'], this what we arranged at the frontend